# Propagating sound waves on a 3-D semi bounded domain

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, differential-equations

So in my course notes, we are investigating a sound wave that is propagating through a rigid cylinder with radius $R$. The wave equation is given in cylindrical coordinates as

$\dfrac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial r^2} + \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{\partial \Phi}{\partial r} + \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial \varphi^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial z^2} = \dfrac{1}{v_S^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial z^2} \qquad 0<r<R, \quad 0<\varphi<2\pi, \quad -\infty < z < \infty$

and boundary condition

$v_r = \dfrac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t} = 0$.

They know say that we can solve this problem with separation of variables because

$\Phi(r, \varphi, z;t) = Q(r)H(\varphi)Z(z)T(t)$.

We then get that

$T(t) = \exp(\pm i\sigma t)$

$H(\varphi) = C_m\sin(m\varphi) + D_m\cos(m\varphi)$

and

$Z(z) = \exp(\pm ikz)$.

We can now rewrite the wave equation as

$\dfrac{d^2Q(r)}{d r^2} + \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{dQ(r)}{d r} + \Big(K^2 - \dfrac{m^2}{r^2}\Big)Q(r) = 0$ with $K^2 = \dfrac{\sigma^2 - k^2v_s^2}{v_s^2}$.

They say that this is a Bessel equation and that the only bounded solutions that satisfy the boundary condition are those with $K^2 > 0$. Has anyony an idea how I can show this?

Comment: Amazingly enough, solutions to the Bessel equation are called "Bessel functions". Google will find you far more information about them than you ever wanted to know!

Comment: Hint: $K^2<0$ corresponds to the modified Bessel equation.